# What's the opposite of stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:? What function takes out the % escapes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

What is the opposite of this:

```
modifiedTitle = [modifiedTitle stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

so that it makes a %20 appear as a space and a %26 appear as a &.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API you're looking for is [`stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 9):

Man...  if only the two relevant methods were listed right next to each other in the documentation....

## [Oh wait.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW39)

Comment: The only flaw in your answer is that Apple seems to change their doc urls about every 30 seconds. ;)

Answer (score 0):

All web-URL's are encoded some way some how.  The most common of these is UTF-8.  You can peruse the [Encoding Standards](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm), but know that %20 is a space and %26 is an ampersand in UTF-8, so use `[myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative:

```
NSString *url = [modalData.imageURL stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

There are other character set too in docs.